# rootless-docker through jenkins pipeline

Tags: jenkins-pipeline

I am running docker as rootless using the Jenkins pipeline. I have written a pipeline for the same.
But when pipeline executes

```
export DOCKER_HOST=unix:///run/user/${USERID}/docker.sock
```

this command it is not working through Jenkins.

I have tried with export this to file and execute but still not working.
when I run env command it is not shown there.

Jenkins Pipeline code

```
    dir("/home/operateadmin/workspace"){
   def USERID = '''$( id |grep uid | awk -F '[ ]' '{print $1}' | awk -F '[(]' '{print $1}'| awk -F '[=]' '{print $2}')'''
    sh '''#!/bin/bash
source /etc/environment
sudo apt-get install -y uidmap
export DOCKER_HOST=unix:///run/user/$USERID/docker.sock  
curl -fsSL https://get.docker.com/rootless | sh
systemctl --user status docker
systemctl --user start docker
'''
 }
}
```

I need to execute

```
export DOCKER_HOST=unix:///run/user/$USERID/docker.sock
```

this command using jenkins.

Answer (score -3):

I did not understand the question. But I see you are still messing around with rootless-docker. Good luck.

... by the way, what's wrong with podman?

Comment: When I ran the rootless kit in jenkins pipeline to automate. at that time I am not able to execute export DOCKER_HOST=unix:///run/user/$USERID/docker.sock this command using jenkins.